# How to echo SOA record like nslookup in PHP?

Tags: php, cloudflare

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXgex.png

My goal is to find current nameservers behind any HTTP Host like this.

```
<?php
$resolver = array( '1.1.1.1' );
$domain = 'community.cloudflare.com.';
$report = dns_get_record( $domain, DNS_SOA, $resolver );

print_r( $report );

?>
```

Prints

```
Array
(
)
```

While it works for google.co.uk

Any idea how can I use PHP native function to get SOA report?

If this doesn't work then I have last option using 1.1.1.1 API which I dont want without trying first PHP way.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, the subdomain `community.cloudflare.com(.)` is part of the zone `cloudflare.com.` Since `community.cloudflare.com(.)` is not a zone (even if it could be), there are no SOA or NS records for it.

What you need to do is to get the SOA record or NS records from the less specific zone, which is `cloudflare.com.` in that case:

**Code**

```
$domain = 'cloudflare.com.';
$report = \dns_get_record($domain, \DNS_NS);
\print_r($report);
```

**Response**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [host] => cloudflare.com
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 21052
            [type] => NS
            [target] => ns3.cloudflare.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [host] => cloudflare.com
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 21052
            [type] => NS
            [target] => ns4.cloudflare.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [host] => cloudflare.com
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 21052
            [type] => NS
            [target] => ns5.cloudflare.com
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [host] => cloudflare.com
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 21052
            [type] => NS
            [target] => ns6.cloudflare.com
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [host] => cloudflare.com
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 21052
            [type] => NS
            [target] => ns7.cloudflare.com
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please check my reply written as answer. I am looking for same in PHP to avoid making call to API and have better performance possibly.

Answer (score 0):

A close to what I was looking for

```
    $host = 'community.cloudflare.com';
    
    $api = "https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query?name=$host&type=NS";
    
    
    
                $response = wp_remote_get( $api, array(
                'timeout' => 3,
                'redirection' => 0,
                'headers' => array( "Accept" => "application/dns-json" ),
                ));
    
                $response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
                $response = json_decode( $response, true );
    
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $response );
echo '</pre>';
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [Status] => 0
    [TC] => 
    [RD] => 1
    [RA] => 1
    [AD] => 1
    [CD] => 
    [Question] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => community.cloudflare.com
                    [type] => 2
                )

        )

    [Authority] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => cloudflare.com
                    [type] => 6
                    [TTL] => 93
                    [data] => ns3.cloudflare.com. dns.cloudflare.com. 2036594323 10000 2400 604800 300
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

See

https://github.com/bluelibraries/dns/blob/main/docs/Records/soa.md

Eg using PHP library (**bluelibraries/dns**):

#### A code sample for a certain domain.

```php
$records = DNS::getRecords('bluelibraries.com', RecordTypes::SOA);

print_r($records);
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => BlueLibraries\Dns\Records\Types\SOA Object
        (
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [host] => bluelibraries.com
                    [ttl] => 3600
                    [serial] => 123456789
                    [retry] => 10
                    [mname] => test.com
                    [refresh] => 3600
                    [minimum-ttl] => 1200
                    [rname] => admin.test.com
                    [expire] => 1800
                    [type] => SOA
                    [class] => IN
                )

        )

)
```

**In action** - **a result** obtained with the same PHP Library from above:

https://gethostinfo.com/records/community.cloudflare.com/soa